# Finding the fourier series representation for a piecewise function

Tags: fourier-series

Expand the given function in the appropriate Fourier series: $$\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases} x+1 &\mbox{if } -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
x-1 &\mbox{if } 0 \leq x \lt 1 \end{cases} 
\end{align}$$

To my knowledge, the first step is to determine whether the function is even or odd and that's where I get stuck.

UPDATE AFTER DISCUSSION WITH MARIANO:

on $[-1,0]$, $f(-x)=-x+1 \neq -f(x)$

on $[0, 1]$, $f(-x)=-x-1 \neq -f(x)$

so now i'm at a loss as to how to continue...

Comment: What is the definition of being odd?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions

Comment: No. Tell me what it means for a function to be odd. (Trust me: I already know the answer. The PhD committee made sure of that)

Comment: $f(-x)=-f(x)$ sorry...i misunderstood u lol

Comment: (I have fixed it)

Comment: So: suppose that $x\in[0,1]$. What is $f(x)$ and what is $f(-x)$ for your specific function?

Comment: $f(x)=x-1$ and $f(-x)=-x+1$

Comment: Ok. So is $f(-x)$ equal to $-f(x)$?

Comment: Yes it is, so it is odd on $[0,1]$, but what about $[-1,0]$ do we just ignore it?

Comment: No. Now suppose that $x$ is in $[-1,0]$. WHat is $f(x)$ and what is $f(-x)$?

Comment: $f(x)=x+1$ and $f(-x)=-x+1$ [PS: i made a mistake in finding $f(-x)$ for the earlier interval, so $f(-x) \neq f(x)$]

Comment: why would you want that $f(-x)$ and $f(x)$ be equal? We are trying to figure out if the function is *odd* at the moment.

Comment: i'm sorry I'm not used to latex, I meant $f(-x) \neq -f(x)$

Comment: I don't see where you think you made a mistake, really. In any case, you probably get the idea of how to check if the function is odd by now. Do it :-)

Comment: ok i'm gonna try to summarize my results above.

Comment: Suppose that $x\in[0,1]$. What is the value of $f(x)$?

Comment: $f(x)=x-1$ 10char

Comment: And is $-x$ positive or negative?

Comment: $-x<0$, so I guess that means $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Comment: Is the function odd?

Comment: yes it is! thank u sir!!

Comment: I'll leave it to someone else to walk you through the computation of the fourier series...

Comment: I understand how to proceed, was just confused about odd-even. ur a lifesaver!!

Comment: The FourierSeries command of the [OrthogonalExpansions](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=33406) package of Maple produces $$\sum _{i=1}^{n}-2\,{\frac {\sin \left( \pi \,ix \right) }{\pi \,i}} .$$

Comment: thank u sir, that's what i ended up getting in my calculations!

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to determine that $f(x)=x+\operatorname{sign}x$ ([sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)), where both terms are odd. Hence $f$ is odd, and we only worry about the sines; thus, integrate $f(x)\sin \pi n x$ over $[0,1]$ and multiply by $2$ to get the coefficient of $\sin \pi n x$ in the expansion. The key ingredient is
$$\int_0^1 (x-1)\,\sin \pi nx \,dx = -\frac{x-1}{\pi n}\cos \pi n x\bigg|_0^1  +\frac{1}{\pi n}\int_0^\pi \cos \pi nx \,dx = -\frac{1}{\pi n}+0 
$$